# How to configure jenkins Build Pipeline to be triggered manually

Tags: jenkins

I want to manually trigger the downstream project in Jenkins. I already installed the [Build Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin), but when I added a `Post-build-action -> build other projects`, it doesn't have the option to trigger the build manually. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

The [Flexible Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) can add triggers to the Build Other Project publisher (post-build task). It doesn't allow a manual trigger but you can trigger on something that you do manually, such as putting a file in a well-known place.  This is compatible with the Pipeline Plugin, though it doesn't take advantage of its power. (You can probably conditionally trigger another job using the Pipeline Plugin and a suitable groovy script, but I can neither confirm nor deny that).

If you're not committed to using the Pipeline Plugin, you could switch to the older [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) which does allow for manual triggering of steps.

Comment: I searched the workflow plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin) it says that it renamed to pipeline plugin. I know I can use the trigger "Build after other projects are built". But I want to do the trigger manually. I don't want to trigger for every commit.

Comment: Ah; I was confusing the Pipeline Plugin with the Build Pipeline Plugin. Naming things is hard :) Then your options are to not trigger automatically (and trigger it manually), or to use the [Flexible Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) along with some configuration.

Comment: I have installed Flexible plugin but I am still not able to find trigger the build manually option.

Comment: You need to configure a trigger that you can do manually. For example, creating a file. And it isn't a true manual triggering either, since you need to do the manual thing before the job reaches the condition point: it doesn't wait indefinitely for you to manually trigger something, it just checks to see if you can already done something.  If you want to wait indefinitely, I think the only plugin that will help is the Build Pipeline Plugin.

Comment: I want to trigger the downstream project manually manually on the pipeline view.  In the pipeline plugin, I couldn't find the option to do that.

Comment: Yes, it's not in the Pipeline Plugin.  If you want a button in the Jenkins UI that triggers a job in the pipeline then you need to switch from the Pipeline Plugin to the Build Pipeline Plugin. They have similar names but they're different plugins.